# DXF image entity group code explanation

Tags: image, cad, dxf

I'm working on a Delphi class to import/export some kind of entities from DXF file.
I'd like add support for Image entity but I don't understand some group codes.

I'm using official DXF guide reference (2002): http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/dxf/dxf2002.pdf

I have understand the group codes 10, 20 and 30, there are the "Insertion point" and work like any other entities.

The problem are group codes:
-11, 21 and 31: U-vector of a single pixel (points along the visual bottom of the image, 
starting at the insertion point) (in WCS);

-12, 22 and 32: V-vector of a single pixel (points along the visual left side of the image, 
starting at the insertion point) (in WCS);

I think DXF use it for scale and rotation but I don't have understand how.

Thanks

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag as the question is in no way related to Delphi at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These group codes are used for controlling the rotation and scale of the image.

Group codes `10`, `20` and `30` control the insertion point of the lower left corner of your image.

The group codes `11`, `21` and `31` are used to define a vector in 3D space that is the endpoint of a line whose start point is assumed to be `0,0,0`, regardless of the origin point of the image.  These group codes describe a relative vector.

This relative vector (for a scale factor of 1) is constrained by a circle  whose radius is the square root of 1/8, or 0.352733677...

For example, an image inserted with no rotation, and a scale factor of 1, would have `11`, `21`, `31` group code values of `0.352733677,0,0` respectively.

An image inserted with no rotation, and a scale factor of 2, would have `11`, `21`, `31` group code values of `0.7054673542,0,0` respectively.

An image inserted with a 45 degree rotation and a scale factor of 1, would have `11`, `21`, `31` group codes of `0.25,0.25,0` respectively.  Which is an oddly even number, but that's the way the math works out.

The scale factor is a multiplier of the circle whose radius is sqrt(1/8).  Once you have this radius based on the scale factor, you can determine the '11' and '21' values using `sin` and `cos` of the rotation angle.

The `12`, `22`, `32` group codes have similar values, but for the left edge of the image.
The same math would be used to determine their values.  It seems like over-constraining the image, but that's the way the specification works.

**EDIT**

The above answer is only valid for a raster image saved at 72 dpi and then inserted into a metric (millimeter scale) drawing.

The formula for figuring out what the proper value (for a scale factor of 1 when inserting the image in the AuoCAD drawing) in the '11' group code, for example, is:

```
(drawing units per inch) / (dpi of image)
```

In a metric dxf drawing that uses millimeters as the drawing units, and a raster image saved at 72 dpi, the scale factor would be `25.4/72 = .35277778`

In a metric dxf drawing that uses millimeters as the drawing units, and a raster image saved at 96 dpi, the scale factor would be `25.4/96 = .26458333`

In an imperial dxf drawing that uses inches as the drawing units, and a raster image saved at 72 dpi, the scale factor would be `1/72 = .013888888`.

In an imperial dxf drawing that uses inches as the drawing units, and a raster image saved at 96 dpi, the scale factor would be `1/96 = .010416667`.

When the dxf file is then opened in a program like AutoCAD, the raster image is drawn at the scale factor shown above, so our first example would be drawn at a size of `width of image in pixels * scale factor in 11`, which for a 100x100px image, would be 35.2778 mm.

Comment: I'm confused. A image is a rectangle. If I have a insert point I need only of a tern of values to orientate the image. Why I need of 2 terns?

Comment: Updated answer, I had some wrong information.  The DXF spec sometimes uses what seems like very complicated notation just to determine something simple like rotation and scale.  Some of this complexity is historical, some of it allows for greater flexibility.

Comment: Now it makes sense. But in this case what is 12, 22 and 32?

Comment: 12, 22, and 32, are the same thing, except for the left edge of the image instead of the bottom.